# How to show live asterisk peer status using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, asteriskami

Hi I am trying to get peer status in asterisk using Node.JS. I went throught couple of API on github and found this:

The Node File:

```
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
    var AsteriskAmi = require('asterisk-ami');
    var express= require('express');
    var http=require('http');
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var ami = new AsteriskAmi( { port : '5038', host: 'host', username: 'uid', password: 'pwd' } );


    app.get('/', function(req, res){

    //send the index.html file for all requests
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

    });

    http.listen(3001, function(){

    console.log('listening on *:3001');

  });

    ami.on('ami_data', function(data){
    console.log('AMI DATA', data);
    io.sockets.emit('ami_data', data);
     });



    ami.connect(function(response){
    console.log('connected to the AMI');
    setInterval( function() {

    ami.send({action: 'SIPpeerstatus'});           
    
    }, 10000);
  });

    process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    ami.disconnect();
    process.exit(0);

  });
```

The HTML File:

```
<html>
        <head></head>

        <body>
        <table  border="1px" bgcolor="#FAFAD2">
        <tr>

        <th>  Peer Id<pre id="ami_data"></pre></th>
         <th> Peer Status<pre id="ami_data2"></pre></th>
        </tr>
        </table>
          <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          



          <script>

            var socket = io();

            socket.on('ami_data', function (data){  


            var str = document.getElementById("ami_data").innerHTML  += JSON.stringify(data.peer) + "<br>"; 
            var str = document.getElementById("ami_data2").innerHTML  += JSON.stringify(data.peerstatus) + "<br>";
           
            

            });

          </script>



        </body>
        </html>
```

Now this keeps on returning the status on all peers again and again.
[image: Peer Status]

I want to create a html page in which when i click on button it should show only the peer status at that moment of time and not send me the status continuously.